# Creating an Amazon EC2 Role with a specific policy but keep getting an Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a role with a specific policy in aws cloud formation using the yaml language, unfortunately i stumbled upon an error and have no idea how to fix it, the role cannot be created by updating the stack.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTLBo.png This is the error i am getting.

And my code for creating the role is like this:

```
PublicEC2Role:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties: 
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
   Version: "2012-10-17"
   Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal:
       Service:
        - ec2.amazonaws.com
      Action: 
        -'sts:AssumeRole'
  Description: 'PublicEC2Role'
  ManagedPolicyArns: 
    - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
  RoleName: 'PublicEC2Role'
  Tags: 
    - Key: Name
      Value: PublicEC2Role
```

If anyone has an idea on how to create this particular role please tell me.

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, but properly formated code blocks. Same goes for errors.

Comment: I've updated the code.

Comment: And the rest of the code? How do you use the role?

Comment: Fix your indentation. I don't know if the source YAML is wrong, but your posted YAML looks wrong e.g`Type: AWS::IAM::Role` is not indented.

Answer (score 0):

This is a parsing issue with your YAML.

`-'sts:AssumeRole'`

Because there is no space between the hyphen and the single quote, YAML is treating that in a way you don't want, and CloudFormation is not seeing it as a valid IAM action (`sts:AssumeRole`).

If you change it to `- sts:AssumeRole` I think it will work.